# Ubuntu Software can't install GIMP on 22.04 new install

Tags: software-center, vpn, gimp

Previous install of GIMP went smoothly. I messed up an update and did a new Ubuntu install.  The rebuild is almost complete, but GIMP just stopped.

[image]

This just after updating Slimjet.  VPN says the download operating at 60+Kb/s

Just prior to the Slimjet update, Software Center couldn't download headers.

So my question is why would Software Center suggest the internet connection is faulty despite indications otherwise?  Any suggestions welcome.

I'm a Ubuntu primitive noob.

Comment: Archisman's answer worked.

Comment: Why?  How might I have known that?  Trying to learn.

Comment: Ubuntu recently replaced the apt package managing system (inherited from Debian) with its own snap packages. While snap packages offer newer versions, automatic updates and other features, they still are quite new, and sometimes are buggy. APT is around for almost 30 years, and it (almost) always works. The Ubuntu store uses snap by default. APT is still available in the terminal.

Comment: Great answer.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the apt version of GIMP instead of the snap version.

Open a terminal and run the following commands. The first updates the package catalogue for apt, and the second one installs gimp.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gimp
```